How to use React-toastify in multiple components
I have a main project, let's say projectA which import couple of other react components for example a module federated react components projectB.
In the projectA I have installed and imported the react toastify container in the App.js.ProjectB is also imported to App.js. Let's say the App.Js in projectA is like this
const App = () => {
 return(
    <div>
      <ToastifyContainer />
      <ProjectB />
      <OtherCompoentsFromProjectA />
    </div>
 )
}

So, in this case, the toastify container only works with the ProjectA. But,seems like the notification does't work from the projectB. The way only it works if we also import the ToastifyContainer also in projectB. So,it means the more are the components the more imports need to be done for react toastify. Is it the best practices. Or are there any other ways that we can handle it so the toastify components needs to be added only once for example only in projectA.

It does not matter, you can directly show toast using toast function. Check out this from official doc - https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/dispatch-toast-outside-of-react-component

Didn't help much. Any examples with the react components? Using in react components requires the toastContainer to be invoked first before using the toast. So, if there are multiple components are loaded in microfrontend architecture then in each of the web components the toastContainer also needs to be invoked.

If you're not using portals or any iframe with your components, React should share the imports with its children or in this case, with the sibling. So generally speaking, if you lift the state up, it would be enough to share the same libraries across components.
In your case, ProjectB is a sibling of ToastifyContainer, so you need to ensure that those components are also siblings, otherwiser, just lift the ToastContainer to its parent component.
After that you can use the toast function with it.

Yeah, this is how the current structure is. ProjectB is a sibling of ToastifyContainer. But, they are still not working with the same Container. Needed to add one more ToastifyContainer also in the ProjectB which is kind of weird I guess. Could it be some that each of this projectA and projectB has seperate webpack builds and while bunding them together, the toastContainer is not found from the projectB(if not provided)
